# Retain xattrs in files (macOS files on Linux SMB server)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, samba, zfs, file-attributes

I run an SMB4 server on Ubuntu Server 19.04 using ZFS as the server file system (separate from the boot drive). I use this server to store files from my Macs (10.7, 10.8, 10.11, 10.12, 10.13, 10.14). I need to be able to access these files on every version listed, however the main problem I face is the extended attributes (I haven't checked 10.7,10.8,10.14 yet but will need support).

So the issue is that macOS creates these `._` files, which I'm sure we're all too familiar with. I would like to be able to store the extended attributes in the files themselves like macOS does normally on HFS+/APFS drives. How can I enable this treatment? I don't want to *delete* the `._` files because I want to use file/folder icons, descriptions, labels, etc.

Please let me know if there are any settings I need to change in macOS/Ubuntu/Samba/ZFS or elsewhere. `smb.conf` can also be provided at request.

SMB - 4.10.0

Ubuntu - 10.94

zfsutils-linux - 0.7.12-1ubuntu5

Comment: Have you solved this issue?